# AngularJS: Directive with arbitrary start and end symbols

Tags: angularjs, interpolation, directive, brackets

## What?

I'd like to use an Angular `.directive` by using arbitrary start and end symbols, e.g. square brackets:

```
<myDirective>callDirectiveAsUsual</myDirective><!-- usual directive call -->

<div>[[callDirectiveWithArbitrarySymbols]]</div><!-- new directive call -->
```

## Why?

To make using a translation library much easier. Instead of annotating HTML, I would like to write `[[TranslateMePlease!]]`.

## Questions

1. Is it possible to define custom start and end symbols for a `.directive`? (According to the docs, this is not possible.)
2. Do I have to add a custom `$interpolateProvider` to the interpolation pipeline? (Assuming there is such an an interpolation pipeline in Angular.)
3. Do I have to write my own version of `ng-bind`? `ng-bind-custom` which uses its own `$interpolateProviderCustom`, which looks out for square brackets?

Comment: IMHO this is not possible. This is the benefit of AngularJS that it sits on top of standard html markup and doesn't use any extra parsing frameworks. To operate with an element in angular it needs to be a DOM object, thus should be parsed by browser, thus be a valid html tag

Comment: There are several ways to call directives already, You can use your directive as an attribute, class or comment (other than element). I am not clear why you want this.